# Read run_id in airflow operator for non templated fields

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to read `run_id` for DAG in `SnowflakeOperator` to set a session parameter, query_tag. But it seems like the session parameter is not templated.

```py
snowflake_operator = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id='snowflake_task',
    snowflake_conn_id='snowflake_conn',
    sql='resources/some.sql',
    warehouse='my_warehouse',
    database='my_database',
    role='my_role',
    session_parameters={
        'QUERY_TAG': 'dagrun_{{run_id}}'
    }
)
```

How can I reference `run_id` and use it as an input here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the non-templated field templated.

```
class MySnowflakeOperator(SnowflakeOperator):

    template_fields = (
        "session_parameters",
    ) + SnowflakeOperator.template_fields
```

Then you can use it as:

```
snowflake_operator = MySnowflakeOperator(
    task_id='snowflake_task',
    snowflake_conn_id='snowflake_conn',
    sql='resources/some.sql',
    warehouse='my_warehouse',
    database='my_database',
    role='my_role',
    session_parameters={
        'QUERY_TAG': 'dagrun_{{run_id}}'
    }
)
```

Comment: Hey is this the complete definition for class MySnowflakeOperator?

Comment: @mad_ for what was asked in the question, yes. Its a subclass. It has all functionaly of SnowflakeOperator with addition of requested templating.